# SQL Query to select only certain data and remove unnecessary data

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, mysql-workbench

I am looking for a query to select only data which is needed.

Eg:

```
hhhhhhhh@gmail.com#2
hhhhhhh2@gmail.com#3
```

i need a query which would only select email and remove data after this.

Answer (score 1):

If the email is always the stuff before the `'#'`, then use `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(email_with_junk, '#', 1) as email
```